# How to change position / direction of fuzzyfinder popup?

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I am using [fuzzyfinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) for vim, and I would like the popup to start a new window on the bottom of the terminal rather on the top. This behaviour would be similar to the CtrlP plugin and default ido-mode in emacs. I cannot find any customization variables for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there is none; you'd either have to ask the plugin author to provide for such an option, or just pragmatically change the source code. (As there doesn't seem to be a lot if any development for FuzzyFinder, this isn't that bad an option, and you can always do the first option, too.)

I think the change has to be done in `~/.vim/autoload/l9/tempbuffer.vim`; change the *second line* from:

```
function l9#tempbuffer#openScratch(bufname, filetype, lines, topleft, vertical, height, listener)
  let openCmdPrefix = (a:topleft ? 'topleft ' : '')
```

to:

```
  let openCmdPrefix = (a:topleft ? 'botright ' : '')
```